# Skiptoken is not valid when $filter=any is specified

Tags: azure-ad-graph-api

I need to get all users from B2C tenant filtering them by 'issuer' within 'userIdentities' array. I use the following query:

```
https://graph.windows.net/{{tenant}}/users?api-version=1.6&$filter=userIdentities/any(u:u/issuer eq 'disney')
```

The thing is that i can get the first page but as far as 'skipToken' returned by the first response is weird i cannot get all others. Here is an example of 'skipToken' returned:

```
"odata.nextLink": "directoryObjects/$/Microsoft.DirectoryServices.User?$filter=userIdentities/any(u:u/issuer%20eq%20'disney')&$skiptoken=<b>X'0100010001000000000000000000000000000000000000'</b>"
```

(when running normal queries skip token is 10 times longer)

When i specify simple filter query (without 'any') it returns valid 'skipToken' and i can get all the results.

Is it a bug of Graph API or i'm doing smth wrong?

Comment: I am getting a similar issue in a C# app I've developed. Code used to work fine but since updating the version of the Graph DLL from NuGet in Visual Studio, I now get the error: "Specified $skiptoken is invalid." despite not making any actual code changes. I suspect this is a bug, though its strange I've only just encountered this and your post is from 2019...

Answer (score 0):

This was fixed in Microsoft.Graph.Core 2.0.7:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet-core/issues/345